# How can I use InAppPurchaseManager with PhoneGap Build?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm looking at [the PhoneGap documentation on including plugins into your PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/plugins), but InAppPurchaseManager is not there. How can I include it?

Thanks.

Comment: did you find a work around for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should contact them directly via special mailing list below. The mailing list is very active, the team is watching it so they will come back to you shortly.

callback-dev@incubator.apache.org

As per official information it is not possible at present time.

```
Right now, you cannot submit your own plugins to PhoneGap Build and have them included on our system. We are working on the infrastructure changes to allow this support
```